# validation of edit row and insert row in GridView

Tags: asp.net

Simple question? I have a gridview with an insert row in the footer and i have validation controls for that row and the edittemplate how do get it to only validate for that row because when i do an edit it validates the insert row aswell. I just wnat to validate the insert row or edit row.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="PageSettings" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True"   
    DataKeyNames="Id"
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourcePages"
    OnLoad="PageSettings_Load"         
    OnRowDataBound="PageSettings_DataBound"
    OnRowCommand="PageSettings_RowCommand"
    OnRowCreated="PageSettings_RowCreated"
    OnRowEditing="PageSettings_RowEditing" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="PageSettings_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowUpdating="PageSettings_RowUpdating"      
    OnPageIndexChanging="PageSettings_PageIndexChanging"
    OnSorting="PageSettings_Sorting" 
    OnSorted="PageSetting_Sorted"    
    PageSize="2"
    ShowFooter="True"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Page Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valRequireName" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="Name"
                    CssClass="gridview-error"     
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
            </EditItemTemplate> 
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="InsertName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valRequireInsertName" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="InsertName"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>               
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Path" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Path">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Path") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>                    
                <asp:TextBox ID="Path" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Path") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valRequirePath" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="Path"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="InsertPath" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valRequireInsertPath" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="InsertPath"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>   
            </FooterTemplate>               
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Route Value" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="RouteValue">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("RouteValue") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="RouteValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RouteValue") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="InsertRouteValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>               
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RegExp" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="RegExp">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("RegExp") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="RegExp" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegExp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="InsertRegExp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>               
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>                
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a

> Validation Group

Define a separate group for each operation

> SaveRecords

&

> EditRecords

. You have to specify each validation group on the Save/Edit buttons & all corresponding validation controls to fire them for that event.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After a long Time 
but you must add in footer requiredfieldvalidator a validationgroup with a unique name and add this validationgroup to add button